# how to import data from mysql xampp into excel 2013, from local machine

Tags: mysql, excel, xampp

How to import data from mysql xampp into excel, from local machine.
When i am going to data option in excel,then  from other source, then from SQL.
Then it ask server name,. So i am filling localhost. But it saying can't connect to server.
I tried with this as well
'localhost,'root',''
Please help me...thanks

Answer (score 1):

With phpmyadmin, go to the table, then, go to export data and select the format. Then, open the file with Excel and done!

Answer (score 1):

1. select your database from phpmyadmin and then go to export
2. select your format "CVS for MS Excel"

Answer (score 1):

Check the image to import table into the excel

[image]